# python equivalent of '#define func() ' or how to comment out a function call in python

Tags: python, preprocessor, comments

my python code is interlaced with lots of function calls used for (debugging|profiling|tracing etc.)
for example:

```
import logging

logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('hello')
j = 0
for i in range(10):
    j += i
    logging.debug('i %d j %d' % (i,j))
print(j)
logging.debug('bye')
```

i want to #define these resource consuming functions out of the code. something like the c equivalent

```
#define logging.debug(val)
```

yes, i know the logging module logging level mechanism can be used to mask out loggings below set log level.  but, im asking for a general way to have the python interpreter skip functions (that take time to run even if they dont do much)

one idea is to redefine the functions i want to comment out into empty functions:

```
def lazy(*args): pass
logging.debug = lazy
```

the above idea still calls a function, and may create a myriad of other problems

Comment: Well, you can always implement your own simple preprocessor that does the trick. Or, even better, you can use an already existing one. Say https://github.com/trentm/preprocess

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python does not have a preprocessor, although you could run your python source through an external preprocessor to get the same effect - e.g. `sed "/logging.debug/d"` will strip out all the debug logging commands.  This is not very elegant though - you will end up needing some sort of build system to run all your modules through the preprocessor and perhaps create a new directory tree of the processed .py files before running the main script.

Alternatively if you put all your debug statements in an `if __debug__:` block they will get optimised out when python is run with the -O (optimise) flag.

As an aside, I checked the code with the dis module to ensure that it did get optimised away.  I discovered that both

```
if __debug__: doStuff()
```

and

```
if 0: doStuff()
```

are optimised, but

```
if False: doStuff()
```

is not.  This is because False is a regular Python object, and you can in fact do this:

```
>>> False = True
>>> if False: print "Illogical, captain"
Illogical, captain
```

Which seems to me a flaw in the language - hopefully it is fixed in Python 3.

**Edit:**

This is fixed in Python 3:  Assigning to True or False [now gives a SyntaxError](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/library/constants.html).
Since True and False are constants in Python 3, it means that `if False: doStuff()` is now optimised:

```
>>> def f():
...     if False: print( "illogical")
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: prepending if 0: | if __debug__: | if variable: + optimization, whether through a script or a good editor may be the best idea (better than prepending # which does not handle multi line statements). maybe python isnt perfect after all

Comment: @Dave: a nice python virus would inject the line 'False,True=True,False' into the code. wonderful things may happen

Answer (score 2):

Although I think the question is perfectly clear and valid (notwithstanding the many responses that suggest otherwise), the short answer is "there's no support in Python for this".

The only potential solution other than the [preprocessor suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006190/python-equivalent-of-define-func-or-how-to-comment-out-a-function-call-in-p/2006874#2006874) would be to use some [bytecode hacking](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=python+bytecode+hack&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=).  I won't even begin to imagine how this should work in terms of the high-level API, but at a low level you could imagine examining code objects for particular sequences of instructions and re-writing them to eliminate them.

For example, look at the following two functions:

```
>>> def func():
...    if debug:  # analogous to if __debug__:
...       foo
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (debug)
              3 JUMP_IF_FALSE            8 (to 14)
              6 POP_TOP

  3           7 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (foo)
             10 POP_TOP
             11 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 15)
        >>   14 POP_TOP
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here you could scan for the `LOAD_GLOBAL` of `debug`, and eliminate it and everything up to the `JUMP_IF_FALSE` target.

This one is the more traditional C-style debug() function that gets nicely obliterated by a preprocessor:

```
>>> def func2():
...    debug('bar', baz)
>>> dis.dis(func2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (debug)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (baz)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 POP_TOP
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here you would look for `LOAD_GLOBAL` of `debug` and wipe everything up to the corresponding `CALL_FUNCTION`.

Of course, both of those descriptions of what you would do are far simpler than what you'd really need for all but the most simplistic patterns of use, but I think it would be feasible.  Would make a cute project, if nobody's already done it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a module scoped variable?

`from config_module import debug_flag`

and use this "variable" to gate access to the logging function(s). You would build yourself a `logging` module that uses the `debug_flag` to gate the logging functionality.

Comment: so i would have to add a check before every function call?

Comment: @random guy: Dirtier than it already is with all these debug statements??

Comment: @jldupont: wouldnt i have to change all the calls to logging to my wrapper class?

Comment: @cschol: debugging is the most common example i could think off. but this magical feature im requesting is good for other things such as real turn on/off of features

Comment: @random guy: not really: just use the module to configure the logging functionality based on the `debug_flag`.

Comment: @jldupont: im not sure i understand you (im a newbee). how do i prevent python from calling/interpreting any of the logging functions (or any other module,functions etc.) with the help of the debug flag?

Comment: @random guy: have you read "http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#configuring-logging" ? You can configure the logging module based on the `debug_flag` I suggested.

Comment: @jldupont: yes i read it. i have not made myself clear: i know you can configure the logging module to ignore certain logging requests, but, the logging request function calls (e.g. logging.debug()) are still being made. im not looking for a specific solution to the logging module functions, bug a general purpose way to comment out a function in python

Answer (score 0):

I think that completely aboiding the calling on a function is not posible, as Python works in a different way that C. The #define takes place in the pre-compiler, before the code is compiled. In Python, there's no such thing.

If you want to completely remove the calling to debug in a work environment, I think the only way if to actually change the code before execution. With a script previous to execution you could comment/uncomment the debug lines.

Something like this:

File logging.py

```
#Main module
def log():
    print 'logging'

def main():
    log()
    print 'Hello'
    log()
```

File call_log.py

```
import re
#To log or not to log, that's the question
log = True

#Change the loging
with open('logging.py') as f:
    new_data = []
    for line in f:
       if not log and re.match(r'\s*log.*', line):
         #Comment
         line = '#' + line
       if log and re.match(r'#\s*log.*', line):
         #Uncomment
         line = line[1:]
       new_data.append(line)

#Save file with adequate log level
with open('logging.py', 'w') as f:
   f.write(''.join(new_data))


#Call the module
import logging
logging.main()
```

Of course, it has its problems, specially if there are a lot of modules and are complex, but could be usable if you need to absolutely avoid the calling to a function.

Answer (score 0):

define a function that does nothing, ie

```
def nuzzing(*args, **kwargs): pass
```

Then just overload all the functions you want to get rid of with your function, ala

```
logging.debug = nuzzing
```

Comment: my original question includes a variant of this solution

Comment: Yeah but by letting your placeholder function call itself recursively, you're leaving the door open for immediate badness ( max call depth stack exceeded ).

The recent cpython compiler is clever enough to reduce any function that's only pass to a noop anyway, so any calls to it are effectively commented out.

I don't imagine you're going to find a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can't *skip* function calls. You could redefine these as empty though, e.g. by creating another logging object that provides the same interface, but with empty functions.

But by far the cleanest approach is to ignore the low priority log messages (as you suggested):

```
logging.root.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Comment: i havent made myself clear. i am looking for a general purpose python hack to 'comment out' function calls. that is, i want the 'commented' functions not to even be called. your suggestion does not eliminate the function call to logging.debug(). the function gets called, and does some processing. this is what i want to avoid

Comment: You made yourself clear, but I don't think it's pythonic to do what you asked for.